# How can I define a dotted underbar in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I would like to create a dotted underbar in ConTeXt with the `\defineunderbar` mechanism. Is that possible?

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Since there has been no response here, it may be better to ask this question on the context mailing list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was answered on the ConTeXt mailing list. There is a new mechanism that can be used to underline text:

```
\starttext
test {\red\underrandoms{test me}} and \underrandom{test} or
\underrandom{grep} \blank
test {\red\underdashes {test me}} and \underdash  {test} or \underdash
{grep} \blank
test {\red\underdots   {test me}} and \underdot   {test} or \underdot
{grep} \blank
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**PS: I plan to add more details on this works**